# .text. returns an empty string

Tags: python, selenium, tradingview-api

Trying to get the current RSI value from TradingView.com but the .text line returns an empty string instead of the value. Thanks. All help is appreciated.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


PATH = "/Applications/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/GZ2VoO8U/#signin")

# Sign into TradingView

time.sleep(2)
username = " "
password = " "
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlap-manager- 
root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('tv-button__loader').click()
time.sleep(3)  # ensure the page loads (bottleneck)

#Search for the currency pair
driver.find_element_by_name("query").send_keys("AUDUSD", Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(2)

Full_feature = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="js-category- 
content"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/a')
Full_feature.click()

time.sleep(5)

Current_Rsi = driver.find_element_by_class_name("valueValue-3kA0oJs5")
print(Current_Rsi.text) #Returns an empty string
```

Comment: Two questions: 1 Are you looking for the `Stochastic RSI Fast (3, 3, 14, 14)`? 2. Can you confirm you are getting the right values from `driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overlap-manager- 
root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/span').click()`

Comment: I am finding the RSI(14) and the xpath I am trying to get at is driver.find_element_by_xpath(
         '/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[3]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div') However, when I use the xpath it is unable to find the element

Comment: The class name is being used by multiple technicals so I have to revert back to Xpath which returns            
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tr[3]/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div"}

Comment: There are many tags available under "valueValue-3kA0oJs5" class name. you can try searching for elements instead of element. After then you can loop through each element and then try extracting text. Moreover i am new to the trading site so doing know what you exactly searching for. Dont know what is RSI, and where it is in your page.

Comment: I have tried using elements to find the classes however, when I put the variable in a for loop the results still remain the same empty strings. The link in the page is a login page thats where I start when opening a new window but if you'd like you could search for any currency pair to see the charts and add the indicator to reveal the rsi

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code below it is extracting some text, but really I am not sure if this is what you are looking for. I am just trying to help.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/chart/GZ2VoO8U/#signin")

# Sign into TradingView

time.sleep(2)
username = " "
password = " "
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="overlap-manager-root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/div/span').click()
driver.find_element_by_name('username').send_keys(username)
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_name('password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('tv-button__loader').click()
time.sleep(3)  # ensure the page loads (bottleneck)

# Search for the currency pair
driver.find_element_by_name("query").send_keys("AUDUSD", Keys.RETURN)

driver.implicitly_wait(10)
try:
    # This code executes when the browser is maximised.
    Full_feature = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="js-category-content"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/a')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Full_feature)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Full_feature).click(Full_feature).perform()
except:
    # This code executes when the browser is Restore down. (Small Browser)
    Full_feature = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="js-category-content"]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/a')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", Full_feature)
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Full_feature).click(Full_feature).perform()

time.sleep(5)

print(driver.current_url)
Current_Rsi = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("valueValue-3kA0oJs5")

for myele in Current_Rsi:
    if myele.text != "": print(myele.text)
```

Note - If this is what you are looking for then please mark this resolution as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the results aren't what I am looking for is the RSI which is currently sitting at 53.40 and constantly changes as the market opens tomorrow morning. The results returned from yours are the current price and change since the closing.

Comment: I'm looking at this url - https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=FX%3AAUDUSD.  Do let me know where and what is RSI here.

Comment: The top bar has an option indicators in the search bar enter relative strength index click on it and it should appear below the graph. The text/number beside RSI is the text I’m trying to get. Thanks for the help really  appreciate it.